# Obtain a list of test cases for a coded UI project programmatically

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have a coded [UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) project, in which I have a set of test cases recorded (methods).
Is there a way to obtain the list of test cases programmatically (in C#) and also get the description I have given during the recording phase?

Comment: Do you mean you need a list of the methods available inside a specific class?

Comment: We see a list of Test Cases in the Test Case Explorer right, i want that list in my program

Comment: I don't know what Test Cases or Test Case Explorer is... Can you explain more or give example of your code?

Comment: We create a Coded UI Project in Visual Studio to Test some UI (Regression to be specific)...
We record some steps, then we generate code and then playback the same steps...
Now each recording is a Method in The Project and they appear in the Test Case Explorer...
I Want to get this list of Testcases in my program, programatically...

Comment: Ah! My bad, didn't understand that. Sorry.

Comment: Are you talking about a macro?

Comment: @CodeIgnoto nopes, just want to programatically get the list of test case methods and their description

Comment: so when you say a method,i am presuming its a function present inside a class?can you post some screen shots of what you are doing

Comment: Yup they are present in a class, its a normal Coded UI Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework), you can use reflection to search for any method or class with the TestMethod/TestClass attribute.

The same concept is used in *[C# Tutorial - Method Attributes And Reflection](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-method-attributes-and-reflection)* and some more details about reflection is in *[Reflection in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET)*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can create a log file using [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) and like wise you can know every time and everything it does. For writing, you can use `Sustem.IO;` writer and create a text file.